# jQuery and Ajax loading issue

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have this ajax call that also does some jquery that adds some html as well as puts the ajax result in the html that was created.

```
$(document).on('click', '#ajaxcommentbutton1', function() {
var currentDiv = $(this).attr('group');
var pageValue = parseFloat($(this).attr('data'));
var newPage = pageValue + 1;
var newPageid =  '#' + newPage;

$('div[data="' + currentDiv + '"] #commentsContainer > div').before("<div id='" + newPage + "'></div>");

   $.ajax({url:"commentsajax.php",
          type:'POST',              
      dataType:'text',
          data: {id: currentDiv,
               page: newPage},
       success:function(result){
     $('div[data="' + currentDiv + '"] ' + newPageid).html(result);
   }});

   $('div[data="' + currentDiv + '"] #commentsContainer > div:empty').remove();
   $('button[group="' + currentDiv + '"]').attr('data', newPage);
});
```

Couple questions:

1. The first div that is created by jquery is not getting created. The ajax is doing its job and returning what I want but because the div is not being created it does not get put anywhere.
2. I'm not sure why I have to use the `.remove()`;

**HTML:**

```
<div id="somepost" data="1043670098507964416">Poster Name<br>
    <img src="http://stuff/stuff" height="50px" width="50px"> Ben &amp; Harley<br>
    <video width="350" height="350" controls="" loop="">
        <source src="http://stuff/stuff">
        <object data="http://stuff/stuff" width="350" height="350"></object>
    </video>
    <br>FASTER! ??<br>17149 Likes 7117  Comments <br>

    <button type="button" id="ajaxcommentbutton1" group="1043670098507964416" data="4">Load previous comments</button><br>

    <div id="commentsContainer">
        <div id="1">
            <br>
            <img> comment here<br>
            <img> comment here<br>
            <img> comment here<br>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Tested:
1. commenting out the `remove()`; allows the response to be printed, couple things though,duplicates of the jquery created divs are created,and also clicking another post(loads diff set of comment for completely diff post) sometimes works, sometimes doesnt, usually works after like the 3rd click, from some research i think it has to do with event handler and binds?? Im just learning jquery/ajax..

Comment: after creating div, you need to append it to DOM. `$('div[data="' + currentDiv + '"] ' + newPageid).html(result).appendTo($('body');`

Comment: sorry that doesnt do anything